# A struct with a member that sometimes needs to be`const` and sometimes not

Tags: c, warnings, constants

I am working on a program that uses a generic `struct` in many places to shuttle around related values. This struct contains a field `char* s`.

Many functions modify `s`; however, sometimes the struct is used to pass information to functions which will only read it. In these cases often the string used to initialize `s` is a `const char*`. However, assigning it to `s` causes a compiler warning.

Though technically correct, this warning feels wrong, as the function does not modify `s`.
Is there a way around this warning, apart from just casting away the const? Is there some way for a function to promise it will treat a struct member as `const`?

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct mystruct{
  int i;
  char* s;
};

void i_only_read(const struct mystruct *m){
  printf("mystruct: i=%d, s=%s\n", m->i, m->s);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  const char* cstr = "Hello";
  struct mystruct m;
  m.i=99;
  /* gcc warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier
   * from pointer target type
   */
  m.s=cstr;
  i_only_read(&m);
}
```

**Notes**

1. I cannot change the struct's declaration to `const char* s`, because most functions taking pointers to the struct do modify `s`.
2. I guess I could have two structs, one with `char* s` and one with `const char* s`, but this seems very ugly (creates redundancy, needs conversion functions between the two structs).
3. If anyone's interested the program is [Navit](http://navit.sourceforge.net/), the struct is `struct attr`. I created a simple example for this question.

Comment: +1 I am implementing a generic string object which can be initialized with or without copying, and I've also run into this issue. I'm so glad you asked this.

Comment: @H2CO3: Ugh, never mind :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB No problem - if a C-style cast from `const char *` to `(char *)` is safe too, I'd use it happily :)

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, you seem to be able to do this in a `union`:

```
struct mystruct {
    int i;

    union {
        char *s;
        const char *cs;
    };
};
```

Now, the rules for `union` apply: use only the union member that was assigned to.  If the function 'promises' to behave, you can assign the string to `cs` without warning.

Specifically, what you should *not* do is assign to `cs` and then pass the struct as a non-const parameter.

Comment: AFAIK, however, 1. type punning through unions is safe, and 2. qualified and unqualified versions of the same type are guaranteed to have the same representation and alignment requirements, so it's safe to read `s` when `cs` was initialized and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks @H2CO3.  Also, in practice unions tend to be more flexible than the standard describes - but it's good to know this one is legit.

Comment: You should never rely on your "in practice" experience, though. If something isn't in compliance with the Standard, then it does not "work", it only **appears to be working.**

Comment: Anonymous union elements are allowed in C11 (and not C99 or C89).  Section §6.7.2.1 ¶8 applies in C11: _If the struct-declaration-list does not contain any
named members, either directly or via an anonymous structure or anonymous union, the
behavior is undefined._ The corresponding verbiage in C99 was: §6.7.2.1 ¶7: _If the struct-declaration-list contains no named
members, the behavior is undefined._  In C11, §6.7.2.1 ¶2 and §6.7.2.1 ¶13 further describe anonymous structures and unions.

Comment: While this avoids the cast to remove const-ness, it seems a bit like cheating, because there is still no compile-time checking. Might as well be honest and just cast...

Answer (score 2):

Building on paddy's and jxh's ideas, I have come up with a solution that looks practical:

- create a "const version" of the struct, with a `const char*` member
- combine it with a "non-const" version of the struct by using a union

Code:

```
typedef struct const_mystruct {
    int i;
    const char * s;
} const_mystruct;

typedef union {
    struct {
        int i;
        char *s;
    };
    const const_mystruct cms;
} mystruct;
```

This achieves the following goals (analogous to what the `const` qualifier does for simple pointers):

- Functions can accept `const_mystruct*` if they want to promise not to modify the char array, and the compiler will enforce this.
- `mystruct` is available for cases where the char array does need to be modified/`free()`d.
- Finally, a `mystruct` can be converted to a `const_mystruct` by reading `mystruct.cms`. 
  The (potentially dangerous) conversion `const_mystruct` -> `mystruct` by writing `mystruct.cms` is not possible, because `mystruct.cms` is `const` and thus not writable.

Code illustrating the use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
/* [structs omitted] */

void i_only_read(const const_mystruct *m){
  printf("mystruct: i=%d, s=%s\n", m->i, m->s);
}

void i_might_modify(mystruct *m){
  printf("noconst: mystruct: i=%d, s=%s\n", m->i, m->s);
}

int main(void){
  const char* cstr = "Hello";
  const_mystruct cm;
  cm.i=99;
  cm.s=cstr;
  // Method promises not to change the structure: OK.
  i_only_read(&cm);
  // Pass a "constant" structure into a method that might modify it:
  // diagnosed by compiler (warning or error).
  i_might_modify(&cm);
  // Trying to remove "const" from the pointer: compiler will not allow this...
  // m.cms.s=cstr; 

  mystruct m;
  m.i=99;
  m.s=malloc(10);
  // Struct is not "const", so modification is OK.
  i_might_modify(&m);
  // Convert to "const" struct, without cast.
  i_only_read(&(m.cms));
  return 0;
}
```

This gives the same guarantees as using `const` for pointers, which was my goal (sort of a "recursive const").

Potential problems:

- The setup seems rather complex,  other developers will probably have a hard time understanding it (I certainly had).
- It feels clumsy to have two versions of the same `struct`.

I'll see if I can actually use this...

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a little convoluted. It combines @paddy's suggestion of the `union` to allow a `const char *` assignment with another `union` on a `const`-ified version of the data structure to provide strict enforcement.

```
typedef struct const_mystruct {
    const int i;
    const char * const s;
} const_mystruct;

typedef union {
    struct {
        int i;
        union {
            char *s;
            const char *cs;
        };
    };
    const_mystruct cms;
} mystruct;

void i_only_read(const_mystruct *m){
  printf("mystruct: i=%d, s=%s\n", m->i, m->s);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  const char* cstr = "Hello";
  mystruct m;
  m.i=99;
  m.cs=cstr;
  i_only_read(&m.cms);
}
```

Comment: The hacky `union` aside, a slightly different approach is to only make the `const_mystruct` the public version of `mystruct` visible to users of the API. Make the `union` version opaque. This would mean you would have to add more APIs that can modify a `mystruct` on behalf of the caller. The API implementations would cast the `const_mystruct` into the `union` version.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this answer is what your question is trying to avoid.  However, short of using a compiler other than gcc or torquing your code into un-readableness, then sometimes a disciplined approach and few comments in the code solve the problem!

What is the purpose of `const` in the following code fragment?

```
void i_only_read(const struct mystruct *m){
  printf("mystruct: i=%d, s=%s\n", m->i, m->s);
}
```

From C's point of view it implies that this function will NOT modify `mystruct`.  If somehow this definition is giving `gcc` fits, then remove the the `const` verbage and enforce the "do NOT update" perspective in the code.

```
// the programmer can/must only read mystruct
void i_only_read(struct mystruct *m){
  printf("mystruct: i=%d, s=%s\n", m->i, m->s);
}
```

Comment: The `const` was just an attempt to illustrate that I'd like to treat the whole struct as "constant". And yes, it does not actually make sense here (though it does not hurt either).